# IOS Healthkit HeartRate Sample metadata HKPrivateHeartRateContext fatal error

Tags: ios, healthkit

I am getting a fatal error with IOS 11, WatchOS 4.0  and `HealthKit`:

> fatal error:   *** An error occurred while adding a sample to the
>   workout: Optional("Invalid metadata key: _HKPrivateHeartRateContext")

I have not set any metadata for heart rate samples.

In a streaming query I have set my sample type to:

```
let quantityType = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.heartRate)
```

after getting streaming samples I save them with:

```
func saveAddedSamples(_ workout: HKWorkout) {
    if !self.heartRateSamples.isEmpty {
        self.healthStore.add(self.heartRateSamples,to: workout) { (success: Bool, error: Error?) -> Void in
        guard success else {
            fatalError("\n *** An error occurred while adding a " +
                "sample to the workout: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
            }
        self.heartRateSamples.removeAll()
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in watchOS 4.0, fixed in 4.1.